# where can I download previous versions of phonegap?

Tags: cordova

I have a project made with PhoneGap 1.1. I don't want to upgrade to 1.5 or whatever, but I can't find a link to download the 1.1 version again and set up the development environment on my new computer :-S

Do you know if there is any place to download phonegap 1.1?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here on the tags page of their GitHub repo. Version 1.1 is a little ways down

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/tags